# Lapply Giving List of List Results

Tags: r, lapply

I'm having some problems when I try to apply a function to a column. I thought I was doing everything correctly, but it is giving me some pretty insane results. Here is the code:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:10,10,rep=TRUE)))

dummy_fn <-function(col_name){
  if (col_name>5){
    return(1)
  }
  else{
    return(0)
  }
}


df$X11<-lapply(df$X1, dummy_fn)

summary(df$X11)
```

Here is the result I'm getting:
[image: results]

How can I make the results just normal 0 and 1 integers?

Comment: Maybe you'd prefer `sapply` (or for some more type safety, `vapply`). I assume your real code is more complicated, otherwise a simple `ifelse` would probably suffice in this instance.

Comment: `df$X11` is a list and it will summarize each part of the list and not the contents of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unlist. `df$X11 <- unlist(lapply(df$X1, dummy_fn))`

EDIT:

`lapply` returns a list. you can `unlist` the results after using `lapply` as the step above suggests, and that would work.

Alternatively, you may use `sapply` instead. `sapply` simplifies `lapply` and returns a vector or matrix. Basically, it will unlist the result if it can. Otherwise it will return a list (it will behave same as `lapply`). use it with caution, and double check the class of the returned results.

In this case, it is able to simplify the results

```
df$X11<-sapply(df$X1, dummy_fn) #Use sapply

summary(df$X11)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    0.25    1.00    0.70    1.00    1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't need an `lapply` for this

```
dummy_fn <- function(data, columnName) {
           as.integer(data[[columnName]] > 5)
 }

df$X11 <- dummy_fn(df, 'X1')
```